# Using split() on JQuery variable from an API string

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, split

I want to split all the results from a property that get returned from an API by the space. How do I call a Javascript function while getting it with JQuery?

PS. Sorry if I don't have the right language. Still new to learning all the terms.

Here's my code. It's currently returning 'function is undefined'  ...

```
        var tags = $('data.result[i].tags').split(" ");

        console.log(tags)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by split? .split usually splits a string into an array, a jQuery object is an array-like object, so using .split makes no sense. Your jquery selector also makes no sense.

Comment: Can you provide the additional code you are using to retrieve the results, as well as what the results look like?

Comment: I'm guessing what you really intended to do was `data.result[i].tags.split(' ');` but for some reason decided to try to use jQuery for it (jQuery has no string manipulation methods other than .trim)

Comment: What Kevin said--like he posted, the quotes need to go away as well as the jQuery wrapper.

Comment: Give Sarah a break. First post and newly learning. Sarah it would be helpful if you posted more of your code as @Ted suggested

Comment: @ Kevin, exactly what I needed thanks! 

@Chris, thanks for having my back. :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't come with a .split method by default, so if you want one, you'll have to create one.

```
$.fn.split = function () {
    return this; // what did you expect the .split method to do? you already have an array if you get this far.
}
```

sarcasm aside, you probably just wanted to split a string into an array.

```
var tags = data.result[i].tags.split(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Split() -> function split a string in to array

```
var results = data.result[i].tags.split(' ');

for(var i = 0; i<results.length;i++){
console.log(results[i]);
}
```